# Como validar con Js Es6 si existen 3 strings en un array iguales al contenido de un objeto?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Tengo una data en el `dom` que extraigo con un `element.dataset` y me devuelve un `DomstringMap` en un objeto

```
const dataDomElement = {
    "disciplina": "Lifestyle",
    "edad": "Adultos",
    "genero": "Hombre",
    "marca": "Sportswear",
    "tecnologia": "undefined",
    "productid": "534",
    "talle": "L,M,S,XL",
    "color": "Negro"
}
```

y necesito validar si dentro de esa data existen los 3 elementos que tengo en un `array`, para efectuar una ejecución solo si todos coinciden.

Gracias desde ya

```
const dataForValidation = [
    "Lifestyle",
    "Adultos",
    "Negro"
]
```

en este caso todos coinciden.

algo así he venido intentando pero (además de que no funciona) creo que debe haber una forma mas sencilla.

```js
const dataDomElement = {
  "disciplina": "Lifestyle",
  "edad": "Adultos",
  "genero": "Hombre",
  "marca": "Sportswear",
  "tecnologia": "undefined",
  "productid": "534",
  "talle": "L,M,S,XL",
  "color": "Negro"
}

const dataForValidation = [
  "Lifestyle",
  "Adultos",
  "Negro"
]

const qtySubcategories = dataDomElement.length
const qtyForValid = []


for (const attr in dataDomElement) {
  let valid = dataForValidation.filter(category => category === dataDomElement[attr])
  qtyForValid.push(valid)    

}
if(qtyForValid.length == dataForValidation.length){

//function
}else{ 

//function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta puede ser una solución al problema.

```js
const dataDomElement = {
  "disciplina": "Lifestyle",
  "edad": "Adultos",
  "genero": "Hombre",
  "marca": "Sportswear",
  "tecnologia": "undefined",
  "productid": "534",
  "talle": "L,M,S,XL",
  "color": "Negro"
}


const dataForValidation = [
  "Lifestyle",
  "Adultos",
  "Negro"
]

//Obtenemos solo los valores. 
let valores = Object.values(dataDomElement)
//Para organizar los datos modificamos el arreglo.
let esInvalido = dataForValidation.map(valor => {

    let loIncluye = valores.includes(valor)

    return {
      valor,
      loIncluye
    }
  })
  .map(x => x.loIncluye)
  .includes(false)

console.log({
  esInvalido
})

//Versión corta 
let esValido = !dataForValidation.map(valor => valores.includes(valor))
  .includes(false)

console.log({
  esValido
})
```

---

> ## [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
>
> El método `map()` crea un nuevo array con los resultados de la llamada a la función indicada aplicados a cada uno de sus elementos.

> ## [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
>
> El método `Object.values()` devuelve un array con los valores correspondientes a las propiedades enumerables de un objeto. Las propiedades son devueltas en el mismo orden a como lo haría un bucle for...in (la única diferencia es que un bucle for-in también enumera las propiedades en la cadena de prototipo de un objeto).

Comment: algo así también maneje, pero así lo valida de forma individual. necesito ubicar si Todos los valores (en este caso 3) en grupo son validos

Comment: Modifique la respuesta. Se puede acortar,  pero la dejo así para mostrar las acciones que hace.

Comment: excelente! ahora si te entendí. Gracias master, lo voy a intentar con un reducer también por probar

Comment: @Legna, no debería devolver `true`? Según entiendo, en el planteo de la pregunta todos los valores si están en el objeto.

Comment: @Marcos Solo basta agregar un `!` al principio y cambiar el nombre de la variable que da el resultado. Modifique la respuesta corta para que refleje ese comportamiento.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código no funciona porque, sea válido o no que el dato se encuentra, siempre estas agregando al arreglo `qtyForValid`.

#### Solución:

Solo agregar al arreglo `qtyForValid` cuando `valid` tenga datos

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const dataDomElement = {
  "disciplina": "Lifestyle",
  "edad": "Adultos",
  "genero": "Hombre",
  "marca": "Sportswear",
  "tecnologia": "undefined",
  "productid": "534",
  "talle": "L,M,S,XL",
  "color": "Negro"
}

const dataForValidation = [
  "Lifestyle",
  "Adultos",
  "Negro"
]

const qtyForValid = []
for (const attr in dataDomElement) {
  if (dataForValidation.filter(category => category === dataDomElement[attr]).length) {
    qtyForValid.push(attr)
  }
}

console.log(qtyForValid);
console.log(qtyForValid.length == dataForValidation.length);
```

---

Otra solución que podrías aplicar sería la siguiente:

- Obtener los valores de los atributos del objeto `dataDomElement`

  ```
  let objectData = Object.values(dataDomElement);
  ```
- Filtramos que valores del arreglo `dataForValidation` están en el arreglo de datos del objeto.

  ```
  let validData = dataForValidation.filter(val => objectData.includes(val));
  ```
- Comparamos si el largo de arreglo de valores es igual al arreglo de datos encontrados

  ```
  validData.length == dataForValidation.length;
  ```

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const dataDomElement = {
  "disciplina": "Lifestyle",
  "edad": "Adultos",
  "genero": "Hombre",
  "marca": "Sportswear",
  "tecnologia": "undefined",
  "productid": "534",
  "talle": "L,M,S,XL",
  "color": "Negro"
};

const dataForValidation = [
  "Lifestyle",
  "Adultos",
  "Negro"
];

let objectData = Object.values(dataDomElement);
let isValid = dataForValidation.filter(val => objectData.includes(val))
  .length == dataForValidation.length;

console.log({isValid});
```